# Time tracking page switching buttons when click to days, weeks and months

Tags: javascript, for-loop, addeventlistener

My goal here is to increment the `data object` inside the `timeframes and previousTimeframes variable` so that when the button is click it will change the values of hours to daily, weekly, and monthly.

In my `weeklybtn` I have an addEventListener that when click it will run the weekly function. Inside the weekly function it will activate the weekly button, and remove the daily and monthly button. I also added a for loop in the data to increment the values of weekly current and previous. When I `console.log(weeklycurrent)` or `console.log(weeklyprevious)`, I can access the values and it's not a problem. I also use forEach in timeframes to access the `timeframes class` in HTML file and loop the values of `weeklycurrent` inside but it's incrementing each timeframes and it's not looping at all.

Any suggestions on how I can fix it?

```js
let data = [
    {
      "title": "Work",
      "timeframes": {
        "daily": {
          "current": 5,
          "previous": 7
        },
        "weekly": {
          "current": 32,
          "previous": 36
        },
        "monthly": {
          "current": 103,
          "previous": 128
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Play",
      "timeframes": {
        "daily": {
          "current": 1,
          "previous": 2
        },
        "weekly": {
          "current": 10,
          "previous": 8
        },
        "monthly": {
          "current": 23,
          "previous": 29
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Study",
      "timeframes": {
        "daily": {
          "current": 0,
          "previous": 1
        },
        "weekly": {
          "current": 4,
          "previous": 7
        },
        "monthly": {
          "current": 13,
          "previous": 19
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Exercise",
      "timeframes": {
        "daily": {
          "current": 1,
          "previous": 1
        },
        "weekly": {
          "current": 4,
          "previous": 5
        },
        "monthly": {
          "current": 11,
          "previous": 18
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Social",
      "timeframes": {
        "daily": {
          "current": 1,
          "previous": 3
        },
        "weekly": {
          "current": 5,
          "previous": 10
        },
        "monthly": {
          "current": 21,
          "previous": 23
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "title": "Self Care",
      "timeframes": {
        "daily": {
          "current": 0,
          "previous": 1
        },
        "weekly": {
          "current": 2,
          "previous": 2
        },
        "monthly": {
          "current": 7,
          "previous": 11
        }
      }
    }
  ];
  
  const dailybtn = document.querySelector(".dailybtn");
const weeklybtn = document.querySelector(".weeklybtn");
const monthlybtn = document.querySelector(".monthlybtn");
const timeframes = document.querySelectorAll(".timeframes");
const previousTimeframes = document.querySelectorAll(".previoustimeframes");



weeklybtn.addEventListener("click", function weekly () {
    weeklybtn.classList.add("active");
    monthlybtn.classList.remove("active");
    dailybtn.classList.remove("active");
 for (let i of data) {
     let weeklycurrent = i.timeframes.weekly.current;
     let weeklyprevious = i.timeframes.weekly.previous;

    
     timeframes.forEach(x => {
     x.textContent = `${weeklycurrent}hrs`;
    console.log(x)
    })
    
    previousTimeframes.forEach(y => {
        y.textContent = `Last Week - ${weeklyprevious}hrs`
    })  
    //  console.log(weeklyprevious)
     console.log(weeklycurrent)
 }
 
 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <!-- displays site properly based on user's device -->

  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./images/favicon-32x32.png">
  
  <title>Frontend Mentor | Time tracking dashboard</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" media="screen" />

  <!-- Feel free to remove these styles or customise in your own stylesheet  -->
  <style>
    .attribution { font-size: 11px; text-align: center; }
    .attribution a { color: hsl(228, 45%, 44%); }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="navigation">
      <div class="navA">
          <img class="jeremy" src="./images/image-jeremy.png" alt="Jeremy's picture">
        <div class="navtext">
          <p class="navbody">Report for</p>
         <h1> Jeremy Robson</h1>  
        </div>
      </div>
        <ul>
          <li class="dailybtn">Daily</li>
          <li class="weeklybtn">Weekly</li>
          <li class="monthlybtn">Monthly</li>
        </ul>
      
    </div>
 
   <div class="table">
     <div class="content" id="work">
       <!-- <img src="./images/icon-work.svg" alt=""> -->
       <div class="contenttext">
         <h5>Work</h5>
         <img class="ellipsis" src="./images/icon-ellipsis.svg" alt="">
         <h3 class="timeframes">5hrs</h3>
         <p class="previoustimeframes">Yesterday - 7hrs</p>
         <h3 class="daily">5hrs <!-- daily --></h3>
            <p class="yesterday">Yesterday - 7hrs <!-- daily --></p>
        <h3 class="weekly">32hrs <!-- weekly --> </h3>
            <p class="lastweek">Last Week - 36hrs <!-- weekly --></p>
         <h3 class="monthly">103hrs <!-- monthly --></h3>
         <p class="lastmonth">Last Month - 128hrs <!-- monthly --> </p>
       </div>
     </div>

    <div class="content" id="play">
      <!-- <img src="./images/icon-play.svg" alt=""> -->
      <div class="contenttext">       
        <h5>Play</h5>
        <img class="ellipsis" src="./images/icon-ellipsis.svg" alt="">
        <h3 class="timeframes">1hr</h3>
         <p class="previoustimeframes">Yesterday - 2hrs</p>
        <h3 class="daily">1hr <!-- daily --></h3>
          <p class="yesterday">Yesterday - 2hrs <!-- daily --></p>
        <h3 class="weekly">10hrs <!-- weekly --></h3>
          <p class="lastweek">Last Week - 8hrs <!-- weekly --></p>
        <h3 class="monthly">23hrs <!-- monthly --></h3>
          <p class="lastmonth">Last Month - 29hrs <!-- monthly --></p>
      </div>
     </div>

    <div class="content" id="study">
      <!-- <img class="imgcontent" src="./images/icon-study.svg" alt=""> -->
      <div class="contenttext">       
        <h5>Study</h5>
        <img class="ellipsis" src="./images/icon-ellipsis.svg" alt="">
        <h3 class="timeframes">0hrs </h3>
         <p class="previoustimeframes">Yesterday - 1hr </p>
           <h3 class="daily">0hrs <!-- daily --></h3>
          <p class="yesterday">Yesterday - 1hr <!-- daiLast Monthly --></p>
        <h3 class="weekly">4hrs <!-- weekly --></h3>
          <p class="lastweek">Last Week - 7hrs <!-- weekly --></p>
        <h3 class="monthly">13hrs <!-- monthly --></h3>
          <p class="lastmonth">Last Month - 19hrs <!-- monthly --></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="exercise">
      <!-- <img src="./images/icon-exercise.svg" alt=""> -->
      <div class="contenttext">      
        <h5>Exercise</h5>
        <img class="ellipsis" src="./images/icon-ellipsis.svg" alt="">
        <h3 class="timeframes">1hr </h3>
         <p class="previoustimeframes">Yesterday - 1hr</p>
     <h3 class="daily">1hr <!-- daily --></h3>
          <p class="yesterday">Yesterday - 1hr <!-- daily --></p>
        <h3 class="weekly">4hrs <!-- weekly --></h3>
          <p class="lastweek">Last Week - 5hrs <!-- weekly --></p>
        <h3 class="monthly">11hrs <!-- monthly --></h3>
          <p class="lastmonth">Last Month - 18hrs <!-- monthly --></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="social">
      <!-- <img src="./images/icon-social.svg" alt=""> -->
      <div class="contenttext">     
        <h5>Social</h5>
        <img class="ellipsis" src="./images/icon-ellipsis.svg" alt="">
        <h3 class="timeframes">1hr </h3>
         <p class="previoustimeframes">Yesterday - 3hrs</p>
         <h3 class="daily">1hr <!-- daily --></h3>
          <p class="yesterday">Yesterday - 3hrs <!-- daily --></p>
        <h3 class="weekly">5hrs <!-- weekly --></h3>
          <p class="lastweek">Last Week - 10hrs <!-- weekly --></p>
        <h3 class="monthly">21hrs <!-- monthly --></h3>
          <p class="lastmonth">Last Month - 23hrs <!-- monthly --></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="content" id="selfcare">
      <!-- <img src="./images/icon-self-care.svg" alt=""> -->
      <div class="contenttext">       
        <h5>Self Care</h5>
        <img class="ellipsis" src="./images/icon-ellipsis.svg" alt="">
        <h3 class="timeframes">0hrs</h3>
         <p class="previoustimeframes">Yesterday - 1hr</p>
     <h3 class="daily">0hrs <!-- daily --></h3>
          <p class="yesterday">Yesterday - 1hr <!-- daily --></p>
        <h3 class="weekly">2hrs <!-- weekly --></h3>
          <p class="lastweek">Last Week - 2hrs <!-- weekly --></p>
        <h3 class="monthly">7hrs <!-- monthly --></h3>
          <p class="lastmonth">Last Month - 11hrs <!-- monthly --></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  
   </div> 
  
  </div>
  
  <footer class="attribution">
    Challenge by <a href="https://www.frontendmentor.io?ref=challenge" target="_blank">Frontend Mentor</a>. 
    Coded by <a href="#">paumnc</a>.
  </footer>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Each iteration through the data `for (let i of data)` you overwrite the textContent of every timeframe and previousTimeFrame, using forEach.  So when it's complete, the last element of data (self care) would have its weeklycurrent/weeklyprevious values in every timeframe and previousTimeFrame.

Comment: yes, you're right. I also tried the other way around if the for loop is inside the `forEach of timeframes` it's giving me the same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have the same number of timeframe and previousTimeframe elements as you have elements in your data array, give this a try (replace your for loop with this forEach) - here I use the index of the current element to refer to hopefully the correct timeframe/previousTimeframe element.

```
data.forEach((i, index) => { 
  let weeklycurrent = i.timeframes.weekly.current;
  let weeklyprevious = i.timeframes.weekly.previous;

  if (timeframes[index]) {
    timeframes[index].textContent = `${weeklycurrent}hrs`;
  }
  
  if (previousTimeframes[index]) {
    previousTimeframes[index].textContent = `Last Week - ${weeklyprevious}hrs`;
  }
});
```

Comment: Yes, it works!  I get it now. This simplifies what I was trying to do. :) Thank you 